# OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') in round function

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I need to use the round function in my code because at a point the floats became too big and python can't handle them, so i simply implemented it like this:

```
def h(x, theta):
    return theta[0] + theta[1] * x

def err(theta, x, y):
    error = []
    i = 0
    for e in x:
        prevision = h(x[i], theta) - y[i] #part where i putted round function
        prevision = round(prevision, 10)
        print(prevision)
        error.append(prevision)
        i += 1

    return error

def sqrErr(error):
    sqrError = []
    for e in error:
        sqrError.append(e ** 2)

    return sqrError

def errForX(error, x):
    errorForX = []
    i = 0
    for e in error:
        errorForX.append(error[i] * x[i])
        i += 1

    return errorForX

def Theta(theta, error, sqrError, errorForX, lr):
    newThetaList = []
    i = 0
    for e in theta:
        newTheta = 0
        if i == 0: #theta_0
            newTheta = e - lr * (1/2) * sum(error) * ((1/4) * sum(sqrError))

        elif i == 1: #theta:1
            newTheta = e - lr *(1/2) * sum(errorForX) * ((1/4) * sum(sqrError))
        newThetaList.append(newTheta)
        i += 1                                             
    return newThetaList

def Train():
    nLoops = 1000000

    y =[5, 11, 21]
    x = [2, 5, 10]
    theta = [0, 0]
    lr = 0.00021
    prediction = []

    for loop in range(nLoops):
        error = err(theta, x, y)
        sqrError = sqrErr(error)
        errorForX = errForX(error, x)
        theta = Theta(theta, error, sqrError, errorForX, lr)

        predictions = []
        for e in x:
            predictions.append(h(e, theta))

    print("Theta: ")
    print(theta)
    print("Targets: ")
    print(y)
    print("Predictions: ")
    print(predictions)                                   

Train()
```

The numbers became too big and it throws an error.
This is my first ever script of a machine learning algorithm, the squared error became a really long number and i don't how to prevent that, tried to limit to 10 the number of digits of the number that is going to be raised to the second but it didn't work

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/flama/OneDrive/Desktop/rete neurale v3.py", line 74, in <module>
    Train()
  File "C:/Users/flama/OneDrive/Desktop/rete neurale v3.py", line 59, in Train
    sqrError = sqrErr(error)
  File "C:/Users/flama/OneDrive/Desktop/rete neurale v3.py", line 21, in sqrErr
    sqrError.append(e ** 2)
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Comment: Please put your code directly here, not in an image, and include the full traceback text.

Comment: @SamMorgan here you go

Comment: You should remove all references to the image and put any code, output, and traceback directly here. Images are impermanent, text on StackOverflow is....maybe forever?

You also haven't provided the input data to this function to produce the error. Also, the function `h` is not defined.

Comment: my fault, h is a function bu without the full code you can't know it, i'm putting all the ocde rigt now